# Inject Spring repositories and their provided class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Is there a way to extract all `Repositories` as well as the `Class<T>` they are providing?

I have some `Repositories` which are annotated with a Qualifier:

```
@NetworkDataProvider
@Repository
public interface SwitchRepository extends CrudRepository<Switch, SwitchPK>
```

The beans they provide are annotated with metadata which defines the way they will be displayed in the GUI:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Switch implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "switch_name")
    @NotNull
    @UIName(value = "name of switch")
    @UIPrio(value = 2)
    private String name;
```

Now I have to extract all Repositories and their corresponding classes:

```
@Autowired
@NetworkDataProvider
List<Repository<?>> repositories;

public List<RepositoryClassTuple> getAllNetworkDataProvider() {
    return repositories.map(r -> 
        new RepositoryClassTuple(r, /* how to do this */ r.getProidedClass())).asList();
}
```

Is there any Way to do this? I really need the Annotations of the repository provided data beans.

Comment: The annotation `@Repository` is irrelevant here. It is meant for bean as a specialized variant for `@Component`. But in Spring Data interfaces they have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data has a type called `Repositories` that takes a `ListableBeanFactory` which can then be used to inspect the repositories:

```
Repositories repositories = new Repositories(beanFactory);

for (Class<?> domainType : repositories) {
  RepositoryInformation info = repositories.getRepositoryInformationFor(domainType);
  …
}
```

I still wonder why you need to mess with this low-level stuff. Really nothing that normal application code should do .

Comment: How can I go the other way? My repositories are injected as a list with the Qualifier, and i have to find out about their Beans? I googled like crazy but cant find a good example using the `Repositories` class. Do i just inject the default `ListableFactoryBean`? Is there a Way filtering the Repositories got from the `Repositories` class depending their qualifier `@NetworkDataProvider` without using manual reflection while Iterating over them?

Comment: No there's not. You can just declare a bean definition for `Repositories`. What's t reason you need to handle all those repos in the first place? Annotation based qualifiers are quite an anti pattern these days. A dedicated interface might be an easier choice as you can use a BeanPostProcessor then handling the type.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an interface :

```
public interface NetworkRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    Class<T> getType();

}
```

Then you can define your implementions like this :

```
public interface PersonRepository extends NetworkRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Override
    default Class<Person> getType() {
        return Person.class;
   }
}

public interface AnimalRepository extends NetworkRepository<Animal, Long> {

    @Override
    default Class<Animal> getType() {
        return Animal.class;
   }
}
```

Then to get them all :

```
@Autowired
Collection<NetworkRepository> networkRepositories;
```

Finally you can use the `getType()` method to get your class information.

**IMPORTANT :** you have to declare `NetworkRepository` in a package not scannable by `Spring Data`.

Comment: Thank you, but this is really much boilerplate, isnt there a simple way to get the beanclass produced by a repository?

Comment: The other way is to use reflections but i don't think it will be simpler

Comment: When you have around 500 Entities this is just a heavy task.

Comment: Nothing of this is needed. See Spring Data's `Repositories` type.

Comment: About "you have to declare `NetworkRepository` in a package not scannable ...": you can also annotate `NetworkRepository` with `@NoRepositoryBean` to make Spring Data not see it as a `Repository`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an interface named MyRepository

```
public interface MyRepository{

}
```

Then, all your repository classes must implement your interface:

```
@Repository("foo")
public class FooExample implements MyRepository{

}

@Repository("bar")
public class BarExample implements MyRepository{

}
```

Finally you can have a map of MyRepository beans injected:

```
@Component
public class ExampleConsumer {

    private final Map<String, MyRepository> repositories;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleConsumer(Map<String, MyRepository> repositories) {
        this.examples = examples;
    }
}
```

In this case the map will contain two entries:

"foo" -> FooExample instance

"bar" -> BarExample instance

Another way is to use java Reflection to read the annotation

```
Class aClass = TheClass.class;
Annotation annotation = aClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);

if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
    MyAnnotation myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation) annotation;
    System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());
    System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
}
```

Here there is a tutorial

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my problem is that i cannot change the Type from `CrudRepository`, because I depend on SpringData's implementation generation capabilities. My problem is the extraction from a class out of a SpringData Repository.

Comment: But you can make your interface SwitchRepository extends as many interfaces as you want.